# html5 audio player - jquery toggle click play/pause?

Tags: jquery, audio, html

i wonder what i'm doing wrong?

```
    $('.player_audio').click(function() {
    if ($('.player_audio').paused == false) {
        $('.player_audio').pause();
        alert('music paused');
    } else {
        $('.player_audio').play();
        alert('music playing');
    }
});
```

i can't seem to start the audio track if i hit the "player_audio" tag.

```
<div class='thumb audio'><audio class='player_audio' src='$path/$value'></audio></div>
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong or what i have to do to get it working?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Well, I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think jQuery extends/parses those functions and attributes (`.paused`, `.pause()`, `.play()`).

try to access those over the DOM element, like:

```
$('.player_audio').click(function() {
  if (this.paused == false) {
      this.pause();
      alert('music paused');
  } else {
      this.play();
      alert('music playing');
  }
});
```

Comment: any idea why a simple mp3 in my audio_player won't work in firefox 3.6?? it just shows a black rectangle. chrome and safari do not have problems at all!

Comment: As MadBrain pointed out, Firefox doesn't like MP3s.  Use Ogg Vorbis instead.  Isn't standardization wonderful?

Comment: you can use the event variable passed by bind to the function enclosed on your click to get the current target which is a DOMElement function(event){ event.currentTarget.play(); } instead of relying on the keyword this

Comment: The audio doesn't pause in Firefox for some reasons.

Comment: it's not working now. I try but nothing alert on browser

Answer (score 107):

You can call native methods trough trigger in jQuery. Just do this:

```
$('.play').trigger("play");
```

And the same for pause: `$('.play').trigger("pause");`

EDIT: as F... pointed out in the comments, you can do something similar to access properties: `$('.play').prop("paused");`

Comment: Maybe you know how to externally (e.m. using $('.play')) to check is player play or paused ?

Comment: You can access element its methods and properties by jQuery.get e.g. $('.play').get(0) or $('.play)[0] Then you can use the play() or plause() methods and the paused property to check if the video is paused. $('.play').get(0).paused is boolean - true if it is paused, false if isn't.

Comment: It may be old but you can access the paused attributes with `$('.play').prop("paused");`

Comment: Also helpful if you need to set play time to 0 :  $(".audioDemo").prop("currentTime",0);

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure why, but I needed to use the old skool document.getElementById();

```
<audio id="player" src="http://audio.micronemez.com:8000/micronemez-radio.ogg"> </audio>
<a id="button" title="button">play sound</a>
```

and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var playing = false;

  $('a#button').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("down");

      if (playing == false) {
          document.getElementById('player').play();
          playing = true;
          $(this).text("stop sound");

      } else {
        document.getElementById('player').pause();
        playing = false;
        $(this).text("restart sound");
      }

  });
});
```

Check out an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HY9ns/1/

Comment: Instead of `getElementById`, you can use jQuery like this: `$('#player').get(0).play()` or `$("#player")[0].play()` .

Answer (score 16):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8834229/1754543) was quite helpful. The jQuery selector need to be told which of the selected elements the following code applies to. The easiest way is to append a

```
    [0]
```

such as

```
    $(".test")[0].play();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, with this you can 'play' & 'pause' at anytime by js.

Comment: This is the right answer.  It isn't hard pulling the element out - simple JQuery basics.

Answer (score 4):

it might be nice toggling in one line of code:

```js
let video = $('video')[0];
video[video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Javascript. Its working for me

Javascript:

```
var myAudioTag = document.getElementById('player_video');
myAudioTag.play();
```

Comment: You should consider updating your answer to match the code in the question - the question doesn't mention an element called `audioTag1`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Add this Code

```
        var status = "play"; // Declare global variable

        if (status == 'pause') {
            status='play';                
        } else {
            status = 'pause';     
        }
        $("#audio").trigger(status);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Firefox does not support mp3 format. To make this work with Firefox, you should use the ogg format.

Comment: This should have been a comment to the post in questions, not a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mtoogle').toggle(
        function () {
            document.getElementById('playTune').pause();
        },
        function () {
            document.getElementById('playTune').play();
        }
    );
</script>
```

And the working demo

http://demo.ftutorials.com/html5-audio/

Answer (score 0):

I did it inside of a jQuery accordion.

```
$(function() {
        /*video controls*/
            $("#player_video").click(function() {
              if (this.paused == false) {
                  this.pause();
              }
            });
        /*end video controls*/

        var stop = false;
        $("#accordion h3").click(function(event) {
            if (stop) {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                stop = false;
            }
            $("#player_video").click();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else has problem with the above mentioned solutions, I ended up just going for the event:

```
$("#jquery_audioPlayer").jPlayer({
    ready:function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"media/song.mp3"
        })
        ...
    pause: function () {
      $('#yoursoundcontrol').click(function () {
            $("#jquery_audioPlayer").jPlayer('play');
      })
    },
    play: function () {
    $('#yoursoundcontrol').click(function () {
            $("#jquery_audioPlayer").jPlayer('pause');
    })}
});
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The *reason* why your attempt didn't work out is, that you have used a class-selector, which returns a collection of elements, not *an* (=one!) element, which you need to access the players properties and methods. To make it work there's basically three ways, which have been mentioned, but just for an overview:

Get the element – not a collection –  by...

- Iterating over the colllection and fetching *the* element with `this` (like in the accepted answer).
- Using an id-selector, if available.
- Getting the element of a collection, by fetching it, via its position in the collection by appending `[0]` to the selector, which returns the first element of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (if you want to click another element on the page):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
        var bool = $("#player").prop("muted");
        $("#player").prop("muted",!bool);
        if (bool) {
            $("#player").prop("currentTime",0);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use

```
$('audio').trigger('pause');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play it, you should use

```
$("#audio")[0].play();
```

If you want to stop it, you should use

```
$("#audio").stop();
```

I don't know why, but it works!