# How to create html button that runs two functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm trying to create a play and pause button for a little web application I'm creating. I've already made a button that plays and another button that pauses but but now I need a button that'll run the play function when clicked and go back to the pause button when clicked.

```
var audio = new Audio("audio.mp3");

$(".play").click(function () {
    audio.play();
})

$(".pause").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
    $(this).toggleClass(".play");
});
```

And here's the buttons

```
<div class="play"><img src="../images/play.gif"></img></div>

<div class="pause"><img src="../images/pause.gif"></img></div>
```

I know there could be and easy way to make a div change classes every time its clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988050/html5-audio-player-jquery-toggle-click-play-pause

Comment: can't you just use a conditional?  Also check jQuery's addClass and removeClass if you're looking to change classes.

Comment: I've tried a conditional but it didn't work. I'll look into addClass and removeClass though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var audio = new Audio("audio.mp3");

$(".play").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".pause").show();
    audio.play();
})

$(".pause").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
    $(this).hide();
    $(".play").show();
    $(this).toggleClass(".play");
});
```

this is the simplest way. it would probably be better to do it with css psuedo classes, but i leave this pleasure to you if you care enough

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. I just added ("play").show() to make the play button show up when it's paused.

Comment: This is so counterintuitive

Answer (score 1):

I would set up the `<html>` like this:

```
<div id="play"><img src="../images/play.gif"></img></div>
<!-- initially a play button -->
```

Then I would just use a boolean to switch back and forth in the script.

```
var toggleIt = false;
$("#play").click(function(){
    if (!toggleIt){
        audio.play();
        toggleIt = true;
        $("#play").find("img").attr("src", "file url here");
    }
    else{
        audio.pause();
        toggleIt = false;
        $("#play").find("img").attr("src", "file url here");
    }
})
```

**edit**: and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/JvGwH/1/) using wonderful [place holder kittens](http://placekitten.com). Yes, you should be grateful for my exquisite taste in placeholder pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable then use a conditional to see if you should either play or pause the audio:

```
<div class="button"><img src="../images/play.gif"></img></div>
```

```
var play = true;
$(".button").click(function(){
    if (play){
        // Play
        audio.play();
        $(".button img").attr("src", "../images/pause.gif");
        play = false;
    } else {
        // Pause
        audio.pause();
        $(".button img").attr("src", "../images/play.gif");
        play = true;
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/f2v32/)

Comment: This bears no relation to the code in the question.  He's not using a button - he's using 2 divs with images in them.

Comment: @Archer He wants a single button to switch between playing and pausing the audio. "now I need a button that'll run the play function when clicked and go back to the pause button when clicked " He doesn't have to use a button, I only used one for the example.

Comment: @Archer, that doesn't really matter.  He set up the code well enough so that it can be easily modified to OP's needs - and further in Charlie's defense, OP wasn't very clear.

Comment: I already tried to run something similar to this but when I did the button still would not play.

Comment: @user3369081 I posted an example on jsFiddle. Take a look at that and modify it to include the actual playing of the audio.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 diferents button and change de visibility

```
var audio = new Audio("audio.mp3");

$("#play").click(function () {
audio.play();
 $("#play").hide();
 $("#pause").show();

})

 $("#pause").click(function () {
 $("#pause").hide();
 $("#play").show();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var audio = new Audio("audio.mp3");

$(".play").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".pause").show();
    audio.play();
})

$(".pause").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
    $(this).hide();
    $(".play").show();
    $(this).toggleClass(".play");
});
```