# One div two functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have looked all over but nothing so far. I'm stuck.

I have an html audio element and I want to control it with a div. When I click on the div it plays the music, but what I need is when I click on it again to stop playing but don't know how.

This is audio tag.

```
<audio class="audioplayer" preload="none" style="display: none;" >
   <source  src="audio/ocean.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

And this is jquery controlling the play with the div (#ocean).

```
$('#ocean').click(function() {
          if ('.audioDemo'.paused == false) {
              $(".audioDemo").trigger('pause');
          } else {
              $(".audioDemo").trigger('play');
          }
        });

        function stopAudio(){
            $(".audioDemo").trigger('pause'); //pause playing
            $(".audioDemo").prop("currentTime",0); //set play time to 0
        }
```

I have wrote stop function and it works but only if I hock it up on another div. I have tried with that .paused but its not working.

How can I use same div as play and stop?

THX

Comment: `if ('.audioDemo'.paused == false) {` the selector is wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5 audio player - jquery toggle click play/pause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988050/html5-audio-player-jquery-toggle-click-play-pause)

Comment: Your class is `audioplayer`, not `audioDemo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings don't have `pause` property, so check `'.audioDemo'.pause` won't work. You need to check plain [`HTMLAudioElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) object `pause` property.

So with the help of jQuery you select `$(".audioDemo")` jQuery object collection, and from there you get raw HTML element as the first element of this collection:

```
$('#ocean').click(function () {
    if ($(".audioDemo")[0].paused == false) {
        $(".audioDemo").trigger('pause');
    } else {
        $(".audioDemo").trigger('play');
    }
});
```

Or a little bit optimized code:

```
$('#ocean').click(function () {
    var $audioObj = $(".audioDemo");
    $audioObj.trigger(!$audioObj[0].paused ? 'pause' : 'play');
});

function stopAudio() {
    $(".audioDemo").trigger('pause').prop("currentTime", 0);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `$audioObj.get(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider this following code:

```
$('#ocean').click(function () {
    if ($(".audioDemo").get(0).paused == false) {
        $(".audioDemo").trigger('pause');
    } else {
        $(".audioDemo").trigger('play');
    }
});
```

You can use following methods while selecting element with index:

```
$("#element")[index]
$("#element").get(index)
$("#element").eq(index)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/q3kmLegq/1/)

> **Note**: <strike>'.audioDemo'.pause</strike> is incorrect for checking audio is paused or not. Means you can't access audio *Object*
>   like this. If you want to do so use *$('element')*.

---

Stop functionality added:

```
$('#stop').click(function(){
    $(".audioDemo").trigger('pause'); //pause playing
    $(".audioDemo").prop("currentTime",0); //set play time to 0
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q3kmLegq/2/)

Comment: `.eq(index)`'s purpose is to select an element by index while retaining the attached jQuery methods and it cannot be used to get the native `audio`element.