# Chaining methods to returned JQuery objects

Tags: jquery

While trying to get a better understanding of `JQuery` I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return)

What I got from it was the `JQuery` selector returns an array-like structure that you can iterate over like an array. My question is under what circumstances can I do something like this:

```
  $('.foo')[1].someFunction();
```

without causing the error: `$(...)[1].someFunction is not a function` (`someFunction` refers to a defined `JQuery` function like `appendTo()`or `text()`) .

Also why will it cause an error and whats the best method (if possible) of chaining a function after using `[]` notation?

Answer (score 3):

> under what circumstances can I do something like this:

```
$('.foo')[1].someFunction();
```

Under **no circumstances**. The objects in the "array" are the native DOM objects, they don't support jQuery functions.

Comment: I've seen people do something like this: `$('.foo')[0].play()` and it work. I know that `play()` is a js function. Is that why it works?

Comment: I have no idea what you've seen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988050/html5-audio-player-jquery-toggle-click-play-pause. Look  for the response by @edwardsharp

Comment: @webDev an `<audio>` DOM element has a `.play()` method natively, no jQuery or anything else

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like [`$('.foo').first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) or [`$('.foo').eq(1)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), which is the more idiomatic way to access the results of a jQuery selector.

As @Amit notes, the objects in the underlying array structure are native DOM elements. A silly but perhaps instructive way to use them in a jQuery method chain would be `$($('.foo')[1]).whatever()`

Getting at the questions asked in comments, native DOM elements have their own (rather large) set of methods that can be called on them. For instance, all HTML Elements have [this very much worth knowing interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) available, and every specific kind of element has it's own extensions of this.

Comment: can you take a look at the question I asked @Amit in the comment section ?

Comment: An <audio> element contains the methods on this page as part of it's native interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: @webDev added more documentation to my answer. That whole site is a tremendous resource for really gaining an understanding of HTML/CSS/JS, how they interact, and what you can and can't do.

Answer (score 1):

When you access a jQuery object with an array selector, the DOM element is returned.  As it's no longer a jQuery object, it will no longer have access to jQuery's methods and properties.

You could try using something like `$('.foo').eq(1)` and then chain jQuery methods off of that.